# Shape of a wavefunction

Tags: quantum-chemistry, orbitals

I am trying to plotting the angular parts of a wavefunction ($Y_{(m,l)}(\theta, \phi)$) with *Wolfram Mathematica*. [this is the table of spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics#Spherical_harmonics).

I think the shape of these function should looks round each part of p and d orbitals is a ellipsoid looks like an egg, like this figure:
[image]

**I have 2 question with my result:**

**1. All my figure of p orbitals only have half part the orbital above(examples:
$p_0$ orbital and $p_y$ orbital). And all the d orbitals looks longer than that above (example: $d_{xz}$).**
[image: $p_0$ orbital] 
[image: $p_y$ orbital]

[image]

**2. When I square the spherical haromics ($[Y_{(m,l)}(\theta, \phi)]^2$), The p orbitals looks the same as the top figure (example: $(p_y)^2$) ,but the p orbitals getting far longer and thinner than that before squared, also the figure in the top (example:$(d_{xz})^2$)**

[image]
[image]

What's wrong with my plot or the shape is not looks like eggs? Do I miss something that make the figure only have half part?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are plotting **different functions**. The figures have no reason to be more than vaguely reminiscent of each other.

Now, those nice puffy things above are the isosurfaces of $\psi$ function. This is a function of three variables, and it just so happens that it can be represented as a product: 
$$\psi(r,\varphi,\vartheta)=R(r)\cdot Y_{\ell,m}(\varphi,\vartheta)$$
You fix a value, find all points in 3D where the function takes that value, and plot them. That's what an isosurface is.

(By now, you might have noticed that the radial part $R(r)$ *never appears at all* in your attempts, so they got to be producing something different. And so they do.)

OK, then what are your plots? These are the spherical graphs of the *angular component alone*. You stay at the origin, point at the direction $(\varphi,\vartheta)$ with a stick having length $Y_{\ell,m}(\varphi,\vartheta)$, and leave a dot there. You don't care at all about the value of $\psi$ at that location. Besides, when $Y_{\ell,m}$ is *negative* (which it is half of the times), you point in the *opposite* direction. This, BTW, is the reason for having only one lobe in your p-orbital-like plots. No wonder you've got both lobes after you've squared $Y_{\ell,m}$ and thus made it always positive.

It could have been worse, you know. Think of a cone with its tip at the origin. Is it an isosurface of any function? Of course it is. What function? For example, $\cos\vartheta$ would do. What is the spherical graph of $\cos\vartheta$? A *sphere*, as you already know. Does a sphere look like a cone? Er, well...